# What does "France going arms" mean?

Tags: meaning

In an episode of Friends, the subtitle read: "France going arms". What does this mean please?

I couldn't find this phrase in the dictionary or on the Internet.

Comment: What language was the film in? What was the spoken dialogue? This is likely to be too localised; in any case there is not enough information to know what was intended. "France going arms" is ungrammatical nonsense [as you found!]

Comment: The dialog was between a man and a woman and the exact quote was "Get your franc going arms away from me" and I saw that on the famous serial film named "Friends" as it can helpful.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It means - *you are going to France, and you take your arms with you, so do not touch me because you have chosen to leave us for a job in Paris*

Or as he says: ***My hugs are reserved for people STAYING IN AMERICA.***

http://home.versatel.nl/friendspic0102/transcripts/html/1015.html

> Rachel: I got a really incredible job offer.
>
> Joey: Hey, great! All right!
>
> Phoebe: Good for you!
>
> Rachel: It's in Paris.
>
> Joey: What? No, no, no! No, no... no... no, no... No, too much is changing, okay? First, Phoebe getting married (to Phoebe) Congratulations! (pointing to Monica and Chandler)... and then these two move into a stupid house in the stupid suburbs...
>
> ...
>
> Phoebe: Of course we can. Congratulations. (they hug, but Joey shakes his head.) Yay! (she gestures Joey to come and join in) Joey...
>
> Joey: No, no, no. My hugs are reserved for people STAYING IN AMERICA.
>
> Rachel: (walking towards Joey) Joey, it would mean so...
>
> Joey: Hey! No! **Get your France-going arms away from me.** (He walks out, and Rachel follows him)

Comment: I believe the second hyphen is wrong; *France-going* is a (newly coined, and unlikely to be much needed) adjective.

Comment: You are correct on both counts. I just pasted from a dialogue. Will correct

Comment: @ mplungjan oh,man whata great answer thnaks